# Finding a subset of the powerset whose union is a specific length

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P_3(S)$ denote the powerset of $S$ where all elements of length greater than $3$ are removed, along with the empty set. Given an integer $l$, how many subsets of $P_3(S)$ $R$ are there such that the length of the union of the members of $R$ is equal to $l$?

*Follow-up*: Can you enumerate the selections?

Comment: Can you let us know what you've tried? Any partial progress that we can give you hints on?
This looks a lot like a homework question so members might not want to just do it for you.

Comment: @Arkady This actually is not a homework problem (if it's that trivial, I would love to get some resources to look at), but it's just a problem that came up and I haven't made much progress.

Comment: I don't mean that the difficulty is homework problem like. Just the way it's phrased as a question and a follow up reminds me of a homework set with a bonus problem. You might consider this section since you are new here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

As for the problem, maybe you can start with solving it for $S$ whose size is $1,2,3,4$ and small values of $l$ to see if a pattern can emerge.

Comment: @Arkady Huh, that must just be the way I phrase it.